# why has my computer mouse started jumping and freezing?

Tags: macos, mouse, freeze, lag

I have an Imac which i have been running on 10.6 for ages and was fine but I just upgraded to 10.9.1.

It was working fine for a week and now my mouse either moves with incredible slowness and short steps requiring multiple swipes to get the cursor across the screen, or it will go quite fast and have the cursor far from where I intended.

My mouse is a wireless optical mouse but I tried a wired optical mouse and there was no change. Is it something in the OSX? or have my mouse drivers betrayed me or something?

If anybody can help it would be greatly appreciated,
It is becoming increasingly irritating and difficult to use.

Thanks,
Ivan.

Comment: Have you tried a (different) mouse mat?

Comment: dirt or hair in the sensor?

Answer (score 0):

Mouse pointers typically slow down when the computer is running hard, accessing the hard drive and/or performing memory operations. The computer can't keep up with redrawing every frame of the pointer so it jumps from point to point as some frames are skipped. I would check what is running in the background and try and free up some resources.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact problem, my pc would even freeze suddenly and would boot to gray flickering screen ( unless I unplug it, pc wouldn't boot). I decided to remove every hardware (apart from the cpu and its fan), and remounted them. I also taped every open ended cable to prevent short circuiting . Now it is working just fine, without any jumping mouse nor pc freezing.

(Ps: I might have plugged in cables from case to mainboard wrongfully, previously. not so sure of this but this possibility is worth considering. just check if +/- poles of the cables on mainboard from case are correct.)